# XSS not working on form

Tags: php, html, xss

Here is a simple form that I want to try and attack with XSS. I am using Chrome.

```
  <?php
    echo  $_GET['comment'];
  ?>
  <script>alert('from HTML')</script>

  <form method="GET" action="">
    Name: 
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <br/><br/>
    Comment:
    <input type="text" name="comment" />
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
```

So I entered into the `comment` text-box the following: `<script>alert('hi')</script>`. However, it's not working. 
The only alert box that pops up is `from HTML` which I have written directly into the code. 
When looking at the page source the following is written:

```
<script>alert('hi')</script>
<script>alert('from HTML')</script>
```

Why is it not executing the first alert?

Comment: Using Chrome with default security settings enabled you'd get something like: `The XSS Auditor refused to execute a script in 'http://x/xss.php?name=&comment=%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%27hello%27%29%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E' because its source code was found within the request. The auditor was enabled as the server sent neither an 'X-XSS-Protection' nor 'Content-Security-Policy' header.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the console tab in the developer tools of your browser. My guess is that your browser has XSS protection enabled.

Comment: how do i switch it off?

Comment: Better use Firefox (without NoScript), switching it off in Chrome seems like a hazzle / not easily possible anymore (http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85044/cannot-turn-off-xss-filter-in-chrome, http://www.frameloss.org/2011/11/01/using-google-chrome-for-security-testing/). Or: Do in PHP `header("X-XSS-Protection: 0");`, then Chrome may allow it.